# Can the focus box around a radio button be removed?

Tags: html

On my page I have a few radio buttons. When one is selected a dashed focus box appears around the button. Can this focus box be removed?

Comment: Obligatory "I wouldn't do this" comment. Focus boxes are hideously ugly, but they're there for a reason: to support keyboard use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to take the focus off the radio button right after it has been clicked.

```
<input type="radio" [...] onclick="this.blur();" />
```